# Binding to event that already occurred and run the handler automatically

Tags: jquery, jquery-events

Referring to the code below, is there a way to bind the "test 2" handler to the "my_event" event *after* "my_event" has occurred so that "test 2" is run right away?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>tests</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script type="text/javascript">

      $(document).bind("my_event", function () {
          alert("test 1");
      });

      $(document).trigger("my_event");

      $(document).bind("my_event", function () {
          alert("test 2");
      });

    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: It sounds like you're asking for a version of `bind` which will fire immediately if the event has every occured in the past.  If so then I don't believe that exists.

Comment: What are you *ultimately* trying to do? Seems like it may be an *XY Problem*.

Comment: There is a race condition problem between $(document).ready and fbAsyncInit when working with Facebook's Javascript SDK as explained here http://pivotallabs.com/users/jdean/blog/articles/1400-working-with-asynchronously-loaded-javascript. I implemented the fix detailed in the same blog post. I am hoping to find a way to replace all my $(document).ready by handlers on that custom event.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Checkout [jQuery's special events](http://brandonaaron.net/blog/2009/06/4/jquery-edge-new-special-event-hooks). Anytime a `"facebookReady"` event is added, the `add` callback will be called, and you can chose to invoke the callback immediately or defer it based on some condition. In this example, I'm looking at the presence of the global `FB` property to decide whether to invoke it.

```
jQuery.event.special.facebookReady = {
    add: function(handleObject) {
        if (window.FB) {
            handleObject.handler.call(this);
        }
    }
};
```

Once the special event's callback is setup, bind the event as you normally would.

```
$(document).bind('facebookReady', ..);
```

Depending on whether FB has loaded on not, it may or may not trigger immediately.

Checkout an [example](http://jsfiddle.net/QDrRY/1/).

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, thank you. The material linked is totally new to me and humbling. I don't see it referenced in the jQuery documentation. Am I missing it?

Comment: I don't think you're missing anything from the jQuery docs. I couldn't find it there either :)

Answer (score 0):

pass the alert value as the extra parameter in the trigger so you can re-use the handler code like

```
$(document).bind("my_event", function (e,param) {
    alert(param);
      });

$(document).trigger("my_event","alert1");
$(document).trigger("my_event","alert2");
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Bs5Db/52/